# Node.js http chat server

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, sockets, node.js-stream

I try create chat server, which will be conncted to Android clients. 1 Client send some data on server, server receive it and send to rest of Clients. So I tried use 'net', but that didn't works. On server i'm listening 1490 port and 192.168.3.XX address. Now my Clients can connect to server, but sending data doesn't work. 
Code:

```
var net = require('http');
var sockets = [];
var tcpServer = net.createServer();

tcpServer.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log(socket.remoteAddress+' connected');
socket.setEncoding('utf8');
sockets.push(socket);
socket.on('data', function(data){
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('data', data);
});
});
tcpServer.listen(1490, '192.168.3.XX');
```

Comment: why you're not using socket.emit, if you want it to send to all the clients? That way you can broadcast to all the registered clients at once.

Comment: @Ravi I even don't get log in console console.log(data);, so that part of code does not work completely

Comment: check the `socket` and `port` you are connecting to, and you should emit data on 'data' event, like `socket.emit('data', 'your data')`.

Comment: @Ravi changed the code, is that correct?

Comment: it seems fine, you should also change the client side code, accordingly. PS i don't know much of Android.

Comment: @Ravi i try again but obviously socket.on('data', function(data) that block doesn't work

Comment: try some debugging on both sides, because i cannot tell/guess the problem without any kind or error or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is on the android client code.

[Check this, hope it helps](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)

```html
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Comment: Its just send data on server, on Android the only problem its how wait or data, because i use WebSocketClient